# PDF header not found exception

Tags: java, pdf, exception, itext7

i'm working with itext 7 and java and my problem is that exception when i try to open an existing pdf file. This is my code

```
    JFileChooser load = new JFileChooser();
    load.setFileFilter(new PdfFilter());
    load.showOpenDialog(this);
    String loadPath = load.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
//some stuff here....


    path = path.concat(".pdf");//path is declared above


    try {
        pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(loadPath), new PdfWriter(path));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ParagrafoFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    doc = new Document(pdf);
    doc.add(new Paragraph("test"));
    doc.close();
```

why doesn't it work?

here the stack trace

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.itextpdf.io.IOException: PDF header not found.
>       at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.getHeaderOffset(PdfTokenizer.java:223)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.getOffsetTokeniser(PdfReader.java:1075)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:120)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:154)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:170)
>       at com.antonionappi.editorpdf.ParagrafoFrame.continuaButtonActionPerformed(ParagrafoFrame.java:1339)
>       at com.antonionappi.editorpdf.ParagrafoFrame.access$2400(ParagrafoFrame.java:46)
>       at com.antonionappi.editorpdf.ParagrafoFrame$25.actionPerformed(ParagrafoFrame.java:404)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Please have a thorough look through your code and make sure you attached the correct version. Do you really use `path` and `loadPath` variables? The exception tells us that the path you provided doesn't seem to be a correct PDF file. Can you make a self-contained example of trying to load PDF file with a hard-coded path and attach the PDF?

Comment: path is a substring of loadPath so it's declared, I split `pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(loadPath), new PdfWriter(path));`                 in `pdf1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(loadPath));
          pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(path));`                                 and now it works

Answer (score 3):

I my case I forgot to close docs:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
//...
doc.close(); //HAVE YOU CLOSE?
pdfDoc.close(); //HAVE YOU CLOSE?
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late here but I was facing the same issue. My issue was that the document was password protected when trying to edit with Adobe. I printed the document to PDF (using Chrome) and it worked after that. (Hopefully this helps)